# Passing sets of properties and nodes as a POST statement wit KOA-NEO4J or BOLT

Tags: node.js, neo4j, koa, neo4j-bolt

I am building a REST API which connects to a NEO4J instance. I am using the koa-neo4j library as the basis (https://github.com/assister-ai/koa-neo4j-starter-kit). I am a beginner at all these technologies but thanks to some help from this forum I have the basic functionality working. For example the below code allows me to create a new node with the label "metric" and set the name and dateAdded propertis.

**URL:**

```
/metric?metricName=Test&dateAdded=2/21/2017
```

**index.js**

```
app.defineAPI({
    method: 'POST',
    route: '/api/v1/imm/metric',
    cypherQueryFile: './src/api/v1/imm/metric/createMetric.cyp'
});
```

**createMetric.cyp"**

```
CREATE (n:metric { 
    name: $metricName, 
    dateAdded: $dateAdded
}) 
return ID(n) as id
```

However, I am struggling to know how I can approach more complicated examples. How can I handle situations when I don't know how many properties will be added when creating a new node beforehand or when I want to create multiple nodes in a single post statement. Ideally I would like to be able to pass something like JSON as part of the POST which would contain all of the nodes, labels and properties that I want to create. Is something like this possible? I tried using the below Cypher query and passing a JSON string in the POST body but it didn't work.

```
UNWIND $props AS properties
CREATE (n:metric)
SET n = properties
RETURN n
```

Would I be better off switching tothe Neo4j Rest API instead of the BOLT protocol and the KOA-NEO4J framework. From my research I thought it was better to use BOLT  but I want to have a Rest API as the middle layer between my front and back end so I am willing to change over if this will be easier in the longer term.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Cypher syntax is bad in a couple of ways.

1. `UNWIND` only accepts a collection as its argument, not a string.
2. `SET n = properties` is only legal if `properties` is a map, not a string.

This query should work for creating a single node (assuming that `$props` is a map containing all the properties you want to store with the newly created node):

```
CREATE (n:metric $props)
RETURN n
```

If you want to create *multiple* nodes, then this query (essentially the same as yours) should work (but only if `$prop_collection` is a *collection of maps*):

```
UNWIND $prop_collection AS props
CREATE (n:metric)
SET n = props
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried your code and passed the following "props=[{metricName:"Test Name",  dateCreated:"02/21/2017"}]" but I get the error "Parameter provided for node creation is not a Map". Clearly I am not structuring the "map" correctly - any pointers on this?

Comment: @n4nite Your props parameter must be a map, and the value you want to use in your query should be an entry in that map whose value is a collection of maps. If we're using cybersam's example, to use the `$prop_collection` parameter, your props would have to be: `props={prop_collection: [{metricName:"Test Name", dateCreated:"02/21/2017"}]}`

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can read up on maps in Neo4j as I can't get this to work and can't find much when I search Google? I am using the examples and passing the "props" string as part of my POST statement to the API but I still get an error that "Parameter provided for node creation is not a Map".

Comment: Thanks - it took me a bit of time to get this working but your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced difficulties when trying to pass complex types as arguments to neo4j, this has to do with type conversions between `js` and `cypher` over `bolt` and there is not much one could do except for filing an issue in the official [neo4j JavaScript driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver) repo. `koa-neo4j` uses the official driver under the hood.

One way to go about such scenarios in `koa-neo4j` is using JavaScript to manipulate the arguments before sending to Cypher:

https://github.com/assister-ai/koa-neo4j#preprocess-lifecycle

Also possible to further manipulate the results of a Cypher query using postProcess lifecycle hook:

https://github.com/assister-ai/koa-neo4j#postprocess-lifecycle

Comment: Hi Keyvan. Thanks for your comments and the great Koa-Neo4j framework. I am new to both Node, Koa and Neo4j so the framework has been a fantastic way to get up and running. Once I get more competent in my coding skills I hope to contribute to the framework!

Comment: Cheers @n4nite, I'd be more than happy to help with any framework related issues that might arise, just [file a GitHub issue](https://github.com/assister-ai/koa-neo4j/issues) if you encountered one. I'm delighted to see that you're doing cool things with `koa-neo4j`.